# Changing the opacity of a CCSprite in a CCSpriteBatchNode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opacity, ccsprite

Can the opacity of a `CCSprite` in a `CCSpriteBatchNode` be modified?

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
((CCSprite *)[batchNode getChildByTag:myTag]).opacity = 0.5;
```

The sprite just disappears instead of showing up with modified opacity.

Comment: what type of texture is the batch node's texture? If it doesn't have an alpha channel (for example RGB565) any opacity < 1 will cause the sprite to disappear because there's no alpha channel, so it can be either fully opaque or not opaque.

Comment: Looks like it's `kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888`.

Comment: Also running a `CCFadeOut` on the sprite works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is why it's a good idea to look at the types. `opacity` property of `CCSprite` is GLubyte. Looking at GLubyte's typedef,  we see that it's actually unsigned char, which means that it takes integer values from 0 to 255. With `sprite.opacity = 0.5` you implicitly convert floating point value to unsigned char, fractional part of 0.5 is truncated, and sprite.opacity becomes 0.